# Running RStudio Server on Openshift Online

Tags: docker, openshift, redhat, rstudio-server

[Openshift Online](https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html) does not allow containers running processes as root for [security reasons](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/) (see the corresponding question in their FAQ section). [RStudio Server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/), on the other hand, requires root privileges for installation and certain operations. According to the [RStudio Server admin guide](http://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/access-and-security.html#server-account):

> RStudio Server runs as the system root user during startup and then
>   drops this privilege and runs as a more restricted user. RStudio
>   Server then re-assumes root privilege for a brief instant when
>   creating R sessions on behalf of users (the server needs to call
>   setresuid when creating the R session, and this call requires root
>   privilege).

Under these circumstances, is it somehow possible to get an RStudio Server docker container running on Openshift Online?

Answer (score 1):

Using OpenShift Online the short answer is no, you will not be able to get it running. You would need to find a Docker image for it which is a single user version and doesn't implement a system whereby is trying to provide it for multiple users and expects to be able to switch user identity.